# Adding styles to a simple maven project

Tags: java, maven, servlets, maven-2

I have created a simple `maven web app` project:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.stsd.project -DartifactId=my-project -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
```

I want this project to be a simple `Servlet` project integerated with `maven` So I don't want to use `spring-mvc` and so on.. wanna keep it as simple as possible.

I have all my resources including of `css` files in `my-project/src/main/resources`

Now I want to link `css` files to my front-ends.. but after deploying the project to a `tomcat` server I can only see messy layout with no css style. I just wonder if I really need to have a `servlet-context.xml` for this to see `css` styles in front view?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it's not working"? Is the server starting correctly (no errors on the console) or are you getting a 404 while typing the URL in the address bar? Short answer: you don't need Spring for that and neither a `servlet-context.xml`.

Comment: I updated the question. I'm not getting any error.. would be nice if you redirect me through some links. tnx.

Comment: Are you directly opening your html files or deploying your app to an application server? (like tomcat or jetty)

Comment: Deploying it to a tomcat server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a file under `/resources` it ends up in `my-project.war/my-project.war/WEB-INF/classes/`.  This is where things go in your *classpath*.   Instead, you should put the css file under `/webapp`.  This will make them go under `my-project.war/`.  These files will now be directly accessible by going to

```
http://localhost:8080/test.css
```